# jmeter User distribution while execution

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter, Scripted the scenario for login of user and goes to the journey of shopping and logout.

Scenario : while running the script want to 100 users to login and only 50 of them should do the shopping.

Please advise how to proceed on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ThroughputController:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller

As a container of the shopping part with 50% set as percentage.

Another option is to use 2 Thread groups:

- one for shopping set at 50 threads
- the other one for navigation set at 50 threads

to reuss common code, use:

- Test Fragment
- Module controller

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1: Using If Controller**

`${__threadNum}` will give the current thread number. So, using the function in the If Controller we can do specific action.

Your test plan will be as given below.

```
Thread Group
     Login
     If Controller  (${__threadNum} < 51)
          Shopping
     If Controller  (${__threadNum} > 50)
          Do something
     Logout
```

**Approach 2: Using Multiple Thread Groups**

I would try to use multiple thread groups as it seems to be very easy to maintain compared to If Controller approach.

```
Thread Group 1  [50 users]

     Login
     Shopping
     Logout

Thread Group 2  [50 users]

     Login
     Some other action
     Logout
```

Comment: Hi Vinoth, thanks for the reply, I also thought for the second option to but my scenario is : Login 100 users and 50 do shopping and logout and rest 50 may do nothing or logout, the scenario is to see when all 100 users login at same time and only 50 continue to do shopping.

Comment: So the second scenario is the easiest for you. You can run those two threads at the same time. Just check if the value is not marked — Run Thread Groups consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your test scenario the options are in:

1. Several [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) like:

   - one Thread Group for not authenticated users
   - another Thread Group for authenticated users
   - one more Thread Group for users who are shopping
2. [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) to set percentage of executions for each sampler
3. [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) - basically for the same, but with fever limits for your fantasy.

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for detailed explanation on each of above approaches.